# How can I divide without flooring in Java?

Tags: java, integer

I'm trying to divide an integer by an integer in Java and return a long result. I tried the following, but I keep getting "0".

```
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(5) / Long.valueOf(18));
System.out.println((long)5 / (long)18);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems everyone has given the right answer, but you should note you can also do

```
System.out.println(5 / 18f)
```

Where f makes it a float

```
System.out.println(5 / 18d)
```

where d makes it a double

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a long, you need a double.

```
System.out.println(5 / 18.0);
```

or

```
System.out.println(5.0 / 18);
```

Of course this will work too:

```
System.out.println(5.0 / 18.0);
```

Answer (score 5):

`Long` is for "long" integer numbers. You should use `float` or `double` instead.

Comment: double should generally be preferred to float nowadays (unless you really care about memory footprint much more than precision)

Answer (score 4):

Longs are still integral, you need a type that can handle decimals, use either `float` or `double`.

```
System.out.println(5.0 / 18.0);
```