# Java Double Mysteriously Rounding

Tags: java, integer, double, rounding

I have this code:

```
package picalculator;

//import java.util.Scanner;

public class PiCalculator {

static int odd=1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    calculatePi();

}
public static void calculatePi() {
    int counter=0;
    double pi=4.0;

    int num[];

    num = new int[20];

    num[0] = generateOdd();
    num[1] = generateOdd();
    num[2] = generateOdd();
    num[3] = generateOdd();
    num[4] = generateOdd();
    num[5] = generateOdd();
    num[6] = generateOdd();
    num[7] = generateOdd();
    num[8] = generateOdd();
    num[9] = generateOdd();
    num[10] = generateOdd();
    num[11] = generateOdd();
    num[12] = generateOdd();
    num[13] = generateOdd();
    num[14] = generateOdd();
    num[15] = generateOdd();
    num[16] = generateOdd();
    num[17] = generateOdd();
    num[18] = generateOdd();
    num[19] = generateOdd();

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        if(counter == 0) {
            pi -= 4/num[i];
            counter++;
        }else {
            pi += 4/num[i];
            counter--;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(pi);

    return;
}
public static int generateOdd() {
    odd += 2;
    return odd;
}

}
```

And for some reason it returns "3.0" even though it should return something more like "3.158..."

It seems like the double is being rounded down to an integer with a ".0" after it. Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no mystery, you're dividing *integers* not doubles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I divide without rounding in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706727/how-can-i-divide-without-rounding-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to cast the result to double.

```
      for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        if(counter == 0) {
            pi -= (double) 4/num[i];
            counter++;
        }else {
            pi += (double) 4/num[i];
            counter--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A cast won't work here; casting an `int` to a `double` still gives a whole number.

Answer (score 8):

Because the expression `4/num[i]`, consisting entirely of integers, is computed using integer math, and always gives a whole number result. If the `4` were a `4.0`, then the expression would be evaluated using `double`, and you'd get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your division is taking place as integer division, so only whole numbers are being subtracted or added to pi. To fix this...

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                pi -= 4.0 / num[i];
                counter++;
            } else {
                pi += 4.0 / num[i];
                counter--;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use D or d as a prefix to tell jvm that it is double not integer.
like this 4D or 4d.
complete example is-

```
double result=4d/3d;
```